# Problema com acentuação ao gerar txt no php

Tags: php, txt, fopen

Pessoal estou usando o código abaixo para gerar um arquivo txt mas está gerando um código estranho.

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8",true);
$fp = fopen("bloco.txt", "w");
$eu = 'é';
fwrite($fp, $eu);
fclose($fp);

?>
```

Comment: testei aqui, abri o txt e lá tem  a letra acentuada `é`

Comment: você está certo, o problema é quando eu exibo o arquivo na tela.isso não é um problema? eu vou consumir ele e salvar as informações no banco de dados.

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução seria abrir o arquivo (`wb`) em modo binário e encodar para utf8 no [`fwrite`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) com [`utf8_encode`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) [como nesta resposta do SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4883133/1284458).

Não testei na minha máquina ainda, mas seria algo assim:

```php
<?php

$fid   = fopen("bloco.txt", "wb")

fwrite($fid, utf8_encode("é"));
fclose($fid);
```